# Update table content using pandastable (Python, tkinter)

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I have a dataframe being displayed in a gui as a table using pandastable. I would like to have this table be frequently updates as new data becomes available (which updates the dataframe columns).

So I wrote this simple example to illustrate the point:

I create the dataframe df, then update it twice in the program by waiting 5 secs between each updates. I expect the GUI to appear then the contents to be updated at the same cadence. Instead the program execute with only the final dt value showing up in the table.

I tried to use .update() and .redraw() instead of .show() to update the values but that didn't work either.

Your input is much appreciated!

```
import pandas as pd
import tkinter as tk
from pandastable import Table
import time

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1,1,1,1,1,1,],
    'B': [1,1,1,1,1,1,],
    'C': [1,1,1,1,1,1,],
    'D': [1,1,1,1,1,1,],
})

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('PandasTable Example')

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

pt = Table(frame, dataframe=df)
pt.show()

time.sleep(5)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [2,2,2,2,2,2,],
    'B': [2,2,2,2,2,2,],
    'C': [2,2,2,2,2,2,],
    'D': [2,2,2,2,2,2,],
})

pt.model.df = df
pt.show()

time.sleep(5)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [3,3,3,3,3,3,],
    'B': [3,3,3,3,3,3,],
    'C': [3,3,3,3,3,3,],
    'D': [3,3,3,3,3,3,],
})

pt.model.df = df
pt.show()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: tkinter widgets get updated only when tkinter `mainloop()` is running.  `root.mainloop()` is executed after you have updated the table model twice, so you can only see the last table model.

Comment: So should I change the order of the code or are you saying that I simply can't do what I was hoping to do?

Comment: For your case, you can add `root.update()` before each `time.sleep(5)`.

Comment: Brilliant! That seems to solve my problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: So what is the right order between root.show() and root.update()?

Comment: you should use `root.after(milliseconds, function_name)` to run function after 5 seconds. And it doesn't block `mainloop`

Comment: there is no `root.show()` but `pt.show()` and it is used like `frame.pack()` to put widget inside window/widget. And `root.update()` is to force `mainloop` to redraw window and all widgets in window. `pandatable` has `pt.redraw()` to redraw table after updating data in model.

Answer (score 2):

`mainloop` starts GUI - it shows/display window. Everything before `mainloop` is only information for `mainloop` what it has to display.

You can use `root.update()` to force `mainloop()` to redraw window.

Or you can use `root.after(milliseconds, function_name)` instead of `sleep` and it will run code after running `mainloop`

You can also use `pt.readraw` instead of `pt.show` after updating `pd.model.df` - it will not flick.

```
import pandas as pd
import tkinter as tk
from pandastable import Table

# --- function ---

def update1():
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A': [2,2,2,2,2,2,],
        'B': [2,2,2,2,2,2,],
        'C': [2,2,2,2,2,2,],
        'D': [2,2,2,2,2,2,],
    })
    
    pt.model.df = df
    #pt.show()
    pt.redraw()

    root.after(5000, update2)
        
def update2():
    
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A': [3,3,3,3,3,3,],
        'B': [3,3,3,3,3,3,],
        'C': [3,3,3,3,3,3,],
        'D': [3,3,3,3,3,3,],
    })
    
    pt.model.df = df
    #pt.show()
    pt.redraw()
    
# --- main ---
    
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1,1,1,1,1,1,],
    'B': [1,1,1,1,1,1,],
    'C': [1,1,1,1,1,1,],
    'D': [1,1,1,1,1,1,],
})

# - gui -

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('PandasTable Example')

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

pt = Table(frame, dataframe=df)
pt.show()

root.after(5000, update1)

root.mainloop()
```

---

If you will run the same code then you could use `after` to run the same function.

```
import pandas as pd
import tkinter as tk
from pandastable import Table

# --- function ---

def update():
    
    pt.model.df += 1
    pt.redraw()
    
    # run again after 5000ms (5s)
    root.after(5000, update)
    
# --- main ---
    
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1,1,1,1,1,1,],
    'B': [1,1,1,1,1,1,],
    'C': [1,1,1,1,1,1,],
    'D': [1,1,1,1,1,1,],
})

# - gui -

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('PandasTable Example')

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

pt = Table(frame, dataframe=df)
pt.show()

root.after(5000, update)

root.mainloop()
```

---

You can see more on my blog in article [Tkinter PandasTable Examples [GB]](https://blog.furas.pl/python-tkinter-pandastable-examples-gb.html)

Comment: Thank you much for your answer Furas, however, in my real code, I want to make the update based on a condition and not based on a static time delay. I know my example is based on time delay but it was just an illustration of a table changing live.

How can I change your last code example to make it update by a condition?

Comment: what condition? I have no idea what you want. You have to show all details to get answer. Usually in GUI we use `Button` to execute function which gets values from other widgets and use in update. You can also assign function to some widgets (ie. `Checkbutton`, `Optionmenu`, `Slider`) and it will execute this function when you change value in widget and this can udpate table. And you can always use some `if/else` in `update()` to update table periodically using conditions.